# Playing video and audio in iPhone directly from server

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have never played with audios and videos in iPhone.
My requirement is :

1.When user selects from the list of podcasts(which I get from the server),I want to play an audio(mp3 file).I have the url for that mp3 file.He should have the controls for playing and pausing the audio(and other normal controls).

2.When user selects from the list of videos(which I get from the server),I want to play a video(m4v file).I have the url for that m4v file.He should have the controls for playing and pausing the video(and other normal controls).

I have read apple documentation as well as many blogs on internet but fail to discover which framework is best suited for my requirements.Is it good to use separate frameworks for audio and video or only single framework will solve the purpose?
Not sure how to deal with the streaming and buffering of the videos and audios.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a feature called **HTTP Live Streaming**. Best if you start with the [official documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).